# Syntax error occurs with cli node/coffeescript app installed globally via npm

Tags: shell, coffeescript, npm, command-line-interface

I have a cli app written in coffee-script.  The cli app uses `commander` (https://github.com/tj/commander.js) to take arguments. I have three files in my bin dir:

```
mediatidy
mediatidy-config
mediatidy-media
```

If I run `bin/mediatidy` in the project folder in bash commander executes fine. If I type `bin/mediatidy config` or `bin/mediatidy media` in bash commander also executes fine and is waiting for an `<action>`.

The odd thing is I published the project to npm and get different results when installed globally. If I install the project via `sudo npm mediatidy -g` (I am using Mac OSX 10.10) I can see the following files in `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
mediatidy
mediatidy-config
mediatidy-media
```

If I run `bin/mediatidy` in the project folder in bash commander executes fine. If I type `bin/mediatidy config` or `bin/mediatidy media` in bash I get the following error:

```
mediatidy config

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mediatidy/bin/mediatidy-config:3
program = require 'commander'
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
     at startup (node.js:119:16)
     at node.js:906:3
Looks like a coffeescript compilation error... wat.
```

If I run the same command but with the dash, `bin/mediatidy-config`, it works fine. I have another app that is private that works without having to use the dash that is globally installed.  What am I missing here?

edit: added my package.json file:

package.json:

```js
{
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "main": "index",
  "name": "mediatidy",
  "description": "Keep your media nice and tidy!",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@github.com:tkdan235/mediatidy.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "directories": {
    "bin": "bin",
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^0.9.0",
    "coffee-script": "^1.8.0",
    "colors": "^0.6.2",
    "commander": "^2.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^0.11.1",
    "lodash": "^2.4.1",
    "nconf": "^0.7.1",
    "node-dir": "^0.1.6",
    "node-ffprobe": "^1.2.2",
    "prompt": "^0.2.14",
    "sqlite3": "^2.2.7"
  },
  "coffeelintConfig": {
    "max_line_length": {
      "name": "max_line_length",
      "value": 120,
      "level": "error",
      "limitComments": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a copy of your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually appears to be a limitation of Commander.js. At first glance, it doesn't appear to call the scripts as shell scripts. Instead, it calls them with node which won't be compiling the CoffeeScript code. See https://github.com/tj/commander.js/blob/master/index.js#L447-L479 (line 469 in particular).

Update:

After some further digging, it looks like this WAS once supported and working. The way sub-commands were called was just their script name. Then this pull request broke it: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/pull/173. The last working version for this behavior was in 2.1.0. You could pin your version to 2.1.0 to get this behavior back.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I had an issue open on the commander repo too with more info I found to resolve the issue.  https://github.com/tj/commander.js/issues/322